# C++ partition_point that works with index information

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

Is there something in C++ that's basically equivalent to partition_point but in which I can use the indices as extra info?

For example, suppose I have a `vector<int> X = {0,1,2,8,9,11}` that I know is sorted and has only nonnegative integers, and I want the first index for which `X[i] != i`. How would I write a binary-search version of this? I know that the predicate `X[i] == i` returns `true true true false false false`.

If i didn't need to use the indices, I could just use `std::partition_point`. I could write my own, but, really, someone has probably already written a bug-free version.

Thanks.

Comment: The usual approach is to zip a range of indices, and operate on the zipped range. Of course, that requires additional library support not present in the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this version.

```
auto it = std::partition_point(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
              [&](const int& e) { return e == (&e - std::data(v)); });
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/DpRKxw).

Not sure if we have guaranty than `e` is a reference of element of `v`.

Comment: Only works for vectors, though, and `std::addressof(v[0])` is just `v.data()`. (No sane `partition_point` implementation would copy the element.)

Comment: @T.C.: and `std::array` or C-array but not for `std::deque`.

Comment: True (also, `basic_string`). So we need C++17 `std::data(v)` (the great benefit is that it doesn't compile for cases where it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

use boost::counting_iterator

```
int solution(int K, int M, vector &A) {
    return *std::partition_point(counting_iterator(0),counting_iterator(M*A.size()),[K,&A](int ls){ return !checkLargeSum(ls,K,A);});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

I ended up just copying the implementation of my compiler into a new function and removing one single *: `_pred(*iter)` -> `_pred(iter)` and using that new function.

Thanks again, your solutions probably work better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, std::lower_bound might work as well, and complexity guarantees to be O(log2(N))

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,8,9,11};

    auto i  = std::lower_bound(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), 0, [&](const int&e, const int&) { return e == (&e - std::addressof(v[0])); });

    std::cout << *i  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```